# Load xml file on start of Windows 8.1 Universal App

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, windows-8.1

in my Windows 8.1 universal app I want to retrieve a local XML file on application start. But I'm confused with async / await. I use GetFileAsync, so it needs to be in an async function. But I could not call it from the initialization of the app. When I just call the function it says i need to add await. If I await, it says I could use await only in an async method, and therefore I could not do it in the initialization. So how could this be done?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

"If you have a simple asynchronous method that doesn't need to synchronize back to its context, then you can use Task.WaitAndUnwrapException"

So put the code into a separate method and use the method above or the second method RunTask.